# Error address blog Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect

I have a question.

I set my address Wordpress to
    `http://www._____.com/main`

And my my address URL 
    `http://www._____.com`

Since today, all my files takes the path URL and not address Wordpress...
It found nothing. No css, no js...

The path became `http://www._____.com/css/style.css` instead of `http://www._____.com/main/css/style.css`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it due to W3 Total Cache... 
I desactived it and reactived it then it works...

Comment: Glad that you found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In wp_options table in db you can change path and urls.